# MySQL previous row calculations

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble saving a variable in a MySQL query. The table I have is simple:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|  SUM(price)  |  timestamp  |
+--------------+-------------+
|433           |2015-05-02   |
+--------------+-------------+
|498           |2015-06-02   |
+--------------+-------------+
|440           |2015-06-04   |
+--------------+-------------+
|434           |2015-06-07   |
+--------------+-------------+
|433           |2015-06-09   |
+--------------+-------------+
```

note that timestamps are not daily/monthly, and there is no index. The above table is the result of the following query:

`SELECT SUM(price) AS totalvalue, timestamp AS ts FROM basetable GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC` which results in a list of dates (timestamp) with the total of all prices in that specific timestamp. (hence the group by, and the order by is for chronology)

What I need is the difference between the current row's total and the row before it, like so:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|  SUM(price)  |  timestamp  |  diff  |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|433           |2015-05-02   |0       |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|498           |2015-06-02   |65      |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|440           |2015-06-04   |-58     |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|434           |2015-06-07   |-6      |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|433           |2015-06-09   |-1      |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
```

all the diff-column does is `current row total - previous row total`. (and 0 for the first row) What I tried to do was save the current row's total in a @variable, and retrieve it in the next row, but I can't get it to work.

The solution is probably simple, but I just can't seem to get it...

UPDATE: I've tried (and failed) these methods:

`SELECT SUM(a.price) AS totalvalue, a.timestamp, SUM(a.price)-COALESCE(SUM(b.price),0) as previous_row_diff 
FROM basetable a 
LEFT JOIN basetable b on a.timestamp=b.timestamp-1`

and

`SET @prev := 0;
SELECT timestamp, SUM(price), SUM(price)-@prev AS diff, @prev := SUM(price) AS diff2
FROM basetable ORDER BY timestamp ASC;`

Both were from this site, as I have no idea how to get this to work...

Comment: Show what you tried? How can we tell you what you did wrong otherwise?

Comment: david in the future create a fiddle

Comment: Hi Drew. SQLFiddle is currently down for me (no building or querying, even with the samples), that's why there's no fiddle. I'll add one when I can

Answer (score 1):

Most other databases support `LAG()`, which makes this much easier.  We can emulate this in MySQL using variables:

```
SELECT totalvalue, ts,
       (CASE WHEN (@save_prev := prev) = NULL THEN NULL  -- = NULL is *never* true
             WHEN (@prev := totalvalue) = NULL THEN NULL -- = NULL is *never* true
             ELSE @save_prev
        END) as prev_value
FROM (SELECT SUM(price) AS totalvalue, timestamp AS ts
      FROM basetable 
      GROUP BY timestamp
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prev := 0) params
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

To get the diff is then easy:

```
SELECT totalvalue, ts,
       (totalvalue -
        (CASE WHEN (@save_prev := prev) = NULL THEN NULL  -- = NULL is *never* true
              WHEN (@prev := totalvalue) = NULL THEN NULL -- = NULL is *never* true
              ELSE @save_prev
         END)
        ) as diff
FROM (SELECT SUM(price) AS totalvalue, timestamp AS ts
      FROM basetable 
      GROUP BY timestamp
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prev := 0) params
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Note:  The use of variables is tricky.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  Hence, all related variable calculations need to be in the same expression.

The above use the sequential evaluation of `CASE` conditions to ensure this.  The `= NULL` is consciously being used as something that always returns false (actually `AND false` or `AND 1 = 0` would do the same thing).  This ensures that the variable values are calculated in the proper order.